# Embedding video-js in a Vaadin 14 Application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm trying to embed video-js into my Vaadin  14 app.  At the moment I just want it to work, so I'm hard coding all the parameters. I'm trying to wrap the  element from video-js in a PolymerElement.  I've imported the video-js module in several places but I can't get it to work.  The same html code works fine in a plain html file.  The  component appears and the 'poster' gets set, bu the video doesn't load and the controls don't show up.

This is my PolymerElement...

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import videojs from 'video.js/dist/video.js';

class MyVideoJS extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html
     <script src="video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
     <video
         id="my-video"
         class="video-js"
         controls
         fluid
         preload="auto"
         poster="https://www.epica.nl/1020_epi_omega_meta-2.jpg"
         data-setup='{"liveui": true }'
         autoplay="true"
       >

          <source src="https://dygu17rhyc0j1.cloudfront.net/out/v1/96e683c9e6b44a03835c3ea47635a4a7/index.m3u8?start=2021-11-08T16:22:00-00:00" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
          <p class="vjs-no-js">
           To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
           web browser that
           <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
         </p>
       </video>
    ;
  }
  handleClick() {
        console.log('Button was clicked.');
        window.alert('Hello');
        var player = videojs('my-video');
  }
}
window.customElements.define('my-video-js', MyVideoJS);
```

And this is my Vaadin Component..

```
@Tag("my-video-js")
@NpmPackage(value = "video.js", version = "^7.8.2")
@JsModule("video.js/dist/video.js")
@CssImport("video.js/dist/video-js.css")

@JsModule("./my-video-js/my-video-js.js")
public class MyVideoJS extends Component {

    public MyVideoJS() {  }

    public void click() {
        getElement().callJsFunction("handleClick");
    }
}
```

Am I doing this the right way??

Thanks,

Stuart.

Comment: Have you checked out https://vaadin.com/directory/component/video-js-player

Comment: I have but it only supports media files local to the app. I started with that as a base. Thx.